# TextBox return wrong value from database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, textbox

I don't know why my textbox return value 0 or 1.

I have simple procedure in sql:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE AB.TicketPrice
    @name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT VALUE 
    FROM AB.Price 
    WHERE Name = @name;
END;
```

I use it as `TableAdapter` and I want load price value.

I have a TextBox with name of ticket: "Nomal Ticket". In DB is the same.

And I have an empty TextBox where I want load price with this code:

```
{
    CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.PriceTicketTableAdapter tmp = new CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.PriceTicketTableAdapter();

    int price;
    string priceS;

    price = tmp.Fill(cinemaDataSet.PriceTicket, NormalTextBox.Text);
    priceS = price.ToString();
    TESTtextBox.Text = priceS;
    MessageBox.Show(priceS);  // I check value
}
```

Comment: Are you positive the value returning from your database is not 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes, because if i check it with combobox and make date binding i have positive value.

Comment: The 0 or 1 might be pertaining to the result of your SPROC then

Comment: What are the names of the database fields for the price, name, etc you are trying to retrieve via that stored procedure?

Comment: I would imagine instead of `select VALUE` in your sproc it should be something like `select @price`

Comment: Table Price with columns:
PriceID PK,
Value (it's price)
Name (it's 'Normal Ticket etc.)

Comment: Textbox in WPF, asp.net, winforms???? Update your tags to answer.

Comment: try changing `select VALUE` to `select @Value`

Comment: It's WindowsForm. Procedure it's fine. I think then problem is with Fill, because it's int (?)

Answer (score 0):

The TableAdapter is configured for a stored procedure? If not it alwais return 0 or 1
In TableAdapter Query Configuration wizard you must select "existing stored procedure"

if you are using SqlCommand you must set

```
yourSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```